# How does a regression tree split the y variable?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cart

How does a regression tree split the y variable? Is it just a case of even chunking of the range or are the chunks of variable size?

Comment: there needs to be a decision-tree tag, but I cant create it

Comment: 'cart' covers decision trees

Comment: When/why does a tree need to split/chunk the target variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target variable is not split, features are. And, this is typically done via a greedy search over the features and possible thresholds. In the end, usually, the target variable of the samples in the leaves are averaged for outputting a prediction.